# catch Ctrl+C in C program

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, signals, openwrt

I use the following code to catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in my C program

***Code***

```
void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGINT) 
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


void main ()
{
    ......

    if(signal(SIGINT, sig_handler)== SIG_ERR) 
    {
        printf(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> SIG INT EROOR !!!! sigint=%d ID=%d \n",SIGINT, getpid());
    }
    else 
        printf(">>>>>>>>>>AFTER>>>>>>>>>>> SIG INT  sigint=%d PID=%d \n",SIGINT, getpid());

    char *buf = NULL;
    asprintf(&buf, "%d", getpid());
    write(fd, buf, strlen(buf));
    free(buf);
    uloop_run(); //entering main loop

    ubus_exit();
    uloop_done();

    xml_exit();
    config_exit();

    free(tmp);

    closelog();

    log_message(NAME, L_NOTICE, "exiting\n");

    return 0;
}
```

My purpose is to catch  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> but it seem the signal handler function i.e `sig_handler()` doesn't run.

I want to know how to fix it?

Answer (score 7):

As [iharob answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27621887/841108), you should add the handler for the signal.

However, you should carefully read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and notice that it is not legal to call `printf` from inside a signal handler (since `printf` is not an *async-signal-safe* function). You should use  [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) instead of [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html).

<sup>This restriction is significant and important. Don't forget that e.g. both `printf` and `malloc` could be interrupted at arbitrary moments, but they are not designed for that.</sup>

At the very least, call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) and/or end your `printf` format string with a `\n`; but that would still be [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (but you might be "unlucky" to have it do what you want most of the time).

BTW, it is recommended today to use [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) instead of the "obsolete" `signal(2)`

In practice, the recommended practice inside a signal handler would be most of the time to set some `volatile sigatomic_t` flag (to be tested outside the handler), or to call [siglongjmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/siglongjmp.3.html). If you insist on doing something else, be sure that you use (even indirectly) only async-signal-safe functions (and there are few of them, mostly the [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) ....). In particular, [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) & [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) should never be used from a signal handler (and that rules out most of the standard C functions, or most of library functions).

You may want to have some [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) around [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (then you might be interested by the Linux specific [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html)....); you should compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then use the `gdb` debugger (and also [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)) to debug your program.

<sup>Are you sure that the functions you are using (e.g. `uloop_run`, etc...) are not blocking or ignoring signals?. You should `strace` your program to find out!</sup>

Comment: I edit the code, and I remove the printf from signal handler but the problem still exist !!

Answer (score 4):

You should add the handler to the signal with this function

```
sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);
```

in your case

```
signal(SIGNINT, sig_handler);
```

One more thing, your `main` function must return `int`, so `void main()` is wrong, it should be `int main()`.

The `uloop_run` function, from [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/) installs a signal handler for `SIGINT` so it's not possible to interrup it, and it overrides your signal handler.

That is the actual reason why your signal handler is never called.

The program wont handle the signal, until the `uloop_run` function exits, this is the `uloop_run` source with the relevant part

```
static void uloop_setup_signals(bool add)
{
    struct sigaction s;
    struct sigaction *act, *oldact;

    memset(&s, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));

    if (add) {
        s.sa_handler = uloop_handle_sigint;
        s.sa_flags = 0;
        act = &s;
        oldact = &org_sighandler;
    } else {
        act = &org_sighandler;
        oldact = NULL;
    }

    sigaction(SIGINT, act, oldact);

    if (uloop_handle_sigchld) {
        if (add) {
            //act already points to s, so no need to update pointer
            s.sa_handler = uloop_sigchld;
            oldact = &org_sighandler_child;
        } else {
            act = &org_sighandler_child;
            oldact = NULL;
        }

        sigaction(SIGCHLD, act, oldact);
    }
}

void uloop_run(void)
{
    struct timeval tv;

    /*
    * Handlers are only updated for the first call to uloop_run() (and restored
    * when this call is done).
    */
    if (!uloop_recursive_count++)
        uloop_setup_signals(true);

    while(!uloop_cancelled)
    {
        uloop_gettime(&tv);
        uloop_gettime(&tv);
        uloop_run_events(uloop_get_next_timeout(&tv));
    }

    if (!--uloop_recursive_count)
        uloop_setup_signals(false);
}
```

as you can see, `uloop_setup_signals(true);` installs a new signal handler for `SIGNINT` and when the loop is finished `uloop_setup_signals(false);` is called restoring the previous signal handler.

So, this is the reason.

Comment: On some systems, `SIGINT` might not be 2. What is normalized by *POSIX* is the C name `SIGINT`, not its value!

Comment: is [while (1) usleep(1000000)]instructions affect the next instructions of my C code !!! .

Comment: @Anis_Stack It's just a way to stop the program until `SIGINT` is recieved, why don't you post the rest of your program?

Comment: What is `uloop_run`? I think it is overriding your signal handler.

Comment: `uloop_run` does add signal handlers, and that's why your program is not working.

Comment: What version of OpenWrt are you using?

Comment: openwrt attitude adjustment

Comment: @Anis_Stack in the previous version of `OpenWrt` it was even worst, since it didn't restore the previous handler, the posted code was actually extracted from a patch to fix the issue.

Comment: @iharob the problem still exist ; when entering the Ctrl + C it's leads to segmentation fault even with the new patch